# Port forwarding not working behind router

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, firewall, port-forwarding

I tried port forwarding to access the HTTP port from outside my LAN. I have an iBall Baton - WRX150NM behind a broadband connection (which uses another modem). To access the internet, the iBall baton modem is configured with a PPPoE connection with username and password given by the ISP. I checks whether the port is open using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Also I have apache server running at 80 and 443.

I have tried the following without any success:

**Added entry into the "Forwarding" table in iBall**  [with port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpSy2.png)

I thought may be the ISP was blocking the port 80.

**So I tried telnet port as well as a random port - 8123 - no success**

I use McAfee LiveSafe. So it manages the firewall settings.

**I tried disabling the firewall in McAfee, enabling port 80 as well as 8123 in the McAfee firewall settings**

I ran tracert in command prompt to google to get the following result:

```
Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  192.168.1.1

  2    66 ms     4 ms     6 ms  103.210.42.2

  3     5 ms     4 ms     5 ms  43.229.88.9

  4    14 ms    15 ms    13 ms  43.227.135.161

  5    22 ms    19 ms    20 ms  172.16.27.65

  6    19 ms    20 ms    20 ms  72.14.209.113

  7    22 ms    22 ms    19 ms  209.85.247.27

  8    20 ms    20 ms    20 ms  209.85.240.139

  9    71 ms    20 ms    21 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
```

I have a desktop on the same network. I tried the same from it too. No Success.

The apache server works perfectly. But port forwarding doesn't seem to work at all. I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the result of test done using Yougetsignal site? Are you testing from within your network or over the external internet? Do you know if your ISP assigns you a Public IP or a Private/Reserved IP?

Comment: ISP assigns me a public ip and it changes each time router starts. When I check using Yougetsignal, I get result that the port is closed. Another site gives me "time out". When I enter my public IP i get from whatismyip in url box (which of course is the same as the ip tested by Yougetsignal), I see the browser enters timeout.

Comment: Is the IP address seen in the router's admin page and on whatismyip same?You may also like to try removing the router in question, running your service on your PC/Laptop being directly connected to your ISP. This will eliminate any incorrect configurations with router. Note that if your ISP follows MAC Id authentication you may have to register the MAC of PC/Laptop with your ISP before you can directly connect it to ISP.

Comment: Can you access the apache server from a different computer from same LAN? (if not, it's **not** a port forwarding problem) Is 192.168.1.100 your apache server? (if not, change the forward rule to the apache server ip)

Comment: I can access apache server from other computers on the same LAN. Also, I tried tunneling tools like Portmap.io and ngrok (which of course, works just fine).